# Custom Comparator based on two properties of an object throws exception

Tags: c++, vector, comparator

I have a list of Business objects, which has properties id and rating, I would like to sort them so that objects with higher ratings appear first, however if the ratings are the same, then original order should be kept.

Code below is implementation:

```
class Business {
public:
    int id;
    int rating;
    Business(int idP, int ratingP) :id(idP), rating(ratingP) {}
};
bool compare(Business b1, Business b2) {
    if (b1.rating != b2.rating) return b1.rating > b2.rating;
    return true;
}
void sortBusinessObjects(vector<Business>& v) {
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
}
```

However when I tested it, it threw exception (I'm using Visual Studio Express and couldn't see exception details)

```
vector<Business> v{ {1, 3},{2, 5}, {9, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 4} };
sortBusinessObjects(v);
```

I'm guessing here the custom comparator return contradictory results for objects in sorting that is causing the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exception?

Comment: sorry I'm using Visual studio express, and it doesn't show exception details. However, I think the logic is very straightforward, I think there might be somethings about C++ sort mechanism that I'm missing

Comment: Look at the output window. It tells you `Expression: invalid comparator`

Comment: I don't see any reason for taking in a reference to a vector<Business> (`vector<Business> &`) in sortBusinessObjects.

Comment: @AndreasH. Is this the issue? my output window only shows *.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Comment: @mikebayko that doesn't make a difference though. I use the reference because I would like to keep the sorted order of the vector after I finish the sorting function :)

Comment: `compare(a, a)` should return false, your comparer breaks that rule.

Comment: @Jarod42 I see, sorry I'm not very familiar with it, so if I return false, then the original order will be kept? If so, that already solved my problem.

Comment: That would just fix your comparer. To keep original order for equivalent item, use `std::stable_sort` instead of `std::sort` as stated in answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 but that's what I want, to keep the original order for equivalent items, and sort other items by ratings from high to low, isn't it?

Comment: You have 2 issues, Andreas H.'s answer fixes both. (even if explications are missing)

Answer (score 4):

You have to write a valid Comparator. Have a look at http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/

> Let f(x, y) be a comparison function. f is in strict weak ordering if
>   it satisfies three invariants:
>
> ```
> Irreflexivity
>    f(x, x) = false.
> Antisymmetry
>    If x!=y and f(x, y) then !f(y, x)
> Transitivity
>    If f(x, y) and f(y, z) then f(x, z).
> Transitivity of Equivalence
>    Let equal(x, y) = !f(x, y) && !f(y, x). If equal(x, y) and equal(y, z) then equal(x, z).
> ```

```
bool compare(Business b1, Business b2)
{
    return b1.rating > b2.rating;
}
```

and you have to use `std::stable_sort` which preserves the order of equal elements (elements where `!f(x,y) && !f(y,x)` with f being the comparison function)

```
void sortBusinessObjects(vector<Business>& v)
{
    stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
}
```

The input

- id=1, rating=3
- id=2, rating=5
- id=9, rating=4
- id=4, rating=3
- id=5, rating=4

creates the output

- id=2, rating=5
- id=9, rating=4
- id=5, rating=4
- id=1, rating=3
- id=4, rating=3

I would prefer a Lambda expression instead of a global comparator because this way all your code ends up in a single, readable function.

```
void sortBusinessObjects(vector<Business>& v)
{
    stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto b1, auto b2) {
        return b1.rating > b2.rating;
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you messed up the reported output: there was no input with `id=9` and `rating=3`. You should also explain (in the question, not a comment) what `stable_sort()` is and why it is needed here.

Comment: Sorry. Had to type this (no copy/paste) and indeed the output is messed up. Will fix this...